# When a hero dies, do you lose equipped trinkets?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

If you equip a trinket on a hero and they are killed, is the trinket lost or is it returned to your trinket inventory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that when a hero falls in combat any trinkets they had equipped become part of the loot pool for that fight, **allowing you to reclaim them if you win that fight.** However, if you retreat from that fight those trinkets will be lost forever.

By extension, if all your heroes fall, then everything equipped by that group will be lost.

I'm not sure what happens to trinkets if a hero falls outside of combat (say, to bleeding).
<sup>Actually, can that even happen...? I can't remember it happening, but maybe I've just been lucky or have a bad memory...</sup>

Comment: So you have to fit it in your party inventory for that mission in order to get it back? Or, does it automatically get dropped back in the trinket inventory back home?

Comment: @walrus If you want to keep them, then yes you'll have to find space to carry them back to base. That can be in the inventory or you could equip them on other heros (but then what do you do with theirs, etc). Don't forget you don't have to take all loot, and can leave something behind.

Comment: You can also use torches and healing items (food, bandage, etc) directly from the loot menu if you are desperate to free up space.